# Alternative to Placement New that does not override placement memory location

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism

I am using polymorphism with virtual functions and need to define a pointer as a child object type before using it. For example:

```
struct object {
  virtual void function() {}
};

struct object_child : object {
  int a;
  int b;
  void function() {std::cout<<"working";}
};

int main() {
  uint64_t sandbox[512];
  object * o1 = new ((void *) &sandbox[0]) object_child();
  o1->function();
}
```

This works fine except that the memory at the location is overwritten. Is there a cast or some operator I can use that would result in the same o1 without overwriting the memory location?

*** EDIT - SK - Adding cout to function -

Comment: `new` creates an `object_child` at that memory location.  Why would you have even written that?

Comment: Is the memory at `0x20000` actually an `object_child`?\

Comment: I do want a pointer cast :). I am just having trouble finding one that works with virtual functions. static and reinterpret cast do not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Memory at 0x2000 is an object_child, but the memory will be reused in the system so it will not have always been an object_child and will not always be either

Comment: All pointer casts work on objects regardless of if the objects have virtual functions.

Comment: Ah, the old "it works fine except"...

Comment: Do you mean `object * o1 = reinterpret_cast<object *>(0x20000);`?

Comment: Ugly things will happen - just drop your idea.

Comment: using : object * o1 = reinterpret_cast<object *>(0x20000);
with the updated function, nothing is printed out because the child type is not in the cast

Comment: @Sam: The child type doesn't need to be in the cast.  If the reinterpret_cast is failing, that means the thing at `0x20000` is NOT actually an `object_child`.  How can we answer a question when you're telling us incorrect information?

Comment: @MooingDuck ... the data structure at 0x20000 matches that of object_child - it was not originally declared as an object_child. Sorry for the confusion. Let me know if there is anything else I can do to clarify.

Comment: Maybe the member variables a and b are there, but that doesn't mean the v-table is there or correct.

Comment: @TonyJ - You are right. I am trying to write software for hardware and was unaware that extra memory was generated for the v-pointer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *say* the bytes at `0x20000` match the data structure layout of `object_child`, but it *actually* doesn't.  Namely, you're overlooking that an `object_child` has an invisible member you're not accounting for - the virtual function pointer.  Which means no pointer cast will work, period.  You'll have to create an *actual* `object_child` object with it's own copy of that state.

Comment: Ok it looks like virtual functions may not be the way to go. thanks